# Tabhost in Android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-tabhost

I am currently following the link below for creating tabhost in Android Eclipse:
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

The problem began at after getting run,the project console shown as

```
[2012-04-14 12:37:25 -AndroidTabhosting] Failed to install AndroidTabhosting.apk on
  device 'emulator-5554': device not found
[2012-04-14 12:37:25 -AndroidTabhosting] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException:device
   not found
[2012-04-14 12:37:25 - AndroidTabhosting] Launch canceled!
```

Can anyone tell me how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried DDMS ? Just open this perspective in Eclipse and see if the emulator is correctly found.
You can also find more information about Android Emulator in the android Dev Guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html)